# c++ Compilation: libnetfilter_queue undefined reference to 'nfq...'

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, debian, netfilter

I am trying to compile libnetfilter_queue package in ubuntu20.04, having installed all necessary dependencies. I have to create a binary file in order to compile it in a IMX8 microprocessor with debian, but when i do the next compilation:

```
g++ -o xg.bin ./src/main.cpp ./src/packet.cpp  -lnetfilter_queue -lssl -lcrypto
```

It throws the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc1h6Iqp.o: in function `on_packet(nfq_q_handle*, nfgenmsg*, nfq_data*, void*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `nfq_get_msg_packet_hdr'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x94): undefined reference to `nfq_get_nfmark'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xad): undefined reference to `nfq_get_payload'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xec): undefined reference to `pktb_alloc(int, void*, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x12d): undefined reference to `nfq_ip_get_hdr(pkt_buff*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x181): undefined reference to `nfq_ip_set_transport_header(pkt_buff*, iphdr*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x1da): undefined reference to `nfq_tcp_get_hdr(pkt_buff*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x1fc): undefined reference to `nfq_tcp_get_payload(tcphdr*, pkt_buff*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x213): undefined reference to `nfq_tcp_get_payload_len(tcphdr*, pkt_buff*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x2c4): undefined reference to `nfq_tcp_compute_checksum_ipv4(tcphdr*, iphdr*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x2d0): undefined reference to `pktb_data(pkt_buff*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x2df): undefined reference to `pktb_len(pkt_buff*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x2fd): undefined reference to `nfq_set_verdict'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x321): undefined reference to `nfq_set_verdict'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x353): undefined reference to `nfq_udp_get_hdr(pkt_buff*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x375): undefined reference to `nfq_udp_get_payload(udphdr*, pkt_buff*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x38c): undefined reference to `nfq_udp_get_payload_len(udphdr*, pkt_buff*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x423): undefined reference to `nfq_udp_compute_checksum_ipv4(udphdr*, iphdr*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x42f): undefined reference to `pktb_data(pkt_buff*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x43e): undefined reference to `pktb_len(pkt_buff*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x45c): undefined reference to `nfq_set_verdict'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x480): undefined reference to `nfq_set_verdict'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x4b5): undefined reference to `nfq_set_verdict'
```

Does anybody know what is happening? I also tried to link the libraries in a manual way via ldconfig, but I figure out that they are already linked. Any idea?

--- COMPILATION FILES ---
**tasks.json:**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    /* Configure Debian SDK Constants from settings.json */
    "options": {
        "env": {
            "CXX": "${config:VARISCITE.CXX}",         /* Used by Makefile */
            "CC": "${config:VARISCITE.CC}",           /* Used by Makefile */
        }
     },
     /* Configure integrated VS Code Terminal */
     "presentation": {
        "echo": false,
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus": true,
        "panel": "dedicated",
        "showReuseMessage": true,
    },
    "tasks": [
        /* Configure Build Task */
        {
            "label": "sudo build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make clean; make -j$(nproc)",
            "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"]
        },
    ]
}
```

**settings.json:**

```
{
    "VARISCITE": {
        /* Target Device Settings */
        "TARGET_IP":"192.168.1.69",

        /* Project Settings */
        "PROGRAM":"xg.bin",
        "PROGRAM_PATH":"build/xg.bin",

        /* Debian SDK Configuration */
        "ARCH":"aarch64-linux-gnu",
        "TOOLCHAIN":"/home/raulgimenez/debian-imx8mm-var-dart/toolchain/gcc-linaro-6.3.1-2017.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu",
        "TARGETSYSROOT":"/home/raulgimenez/debian-imx8mm-var-dart/toolchain/gcc-linaro-6.3.1-2017.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc/usr/include",

        /* Debian SDK Constants */
        "CC_PREFIX": "${config:VARISCITE.TOOLCHAIN}/bin/${config:VARISCITE.ARCH}-",
        "CXX": "${config:VARISCITE.CC_PREFIX}g++ --sysroot=${config:VARISCITE.TARGETSYSROOT}",
        "CC": "${config:VARISCITE.CC_PREFIX}gcc --sysroot=${config:VARISCITE.TARGETSYSROOT}",
    },
    "files.associations": {
        "cstdlib": "cpp"
    },
    "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "enabled"
}
```

**c_cpp_properties.json:**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${config:VARISCITE.TARGETSYSROOT}/**",
                "/usr/include/**"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Thanks in advance,
R.

**UPDATE: I Finally find the paths for using this library, but it fails. It is running on debian installed in a Variscite IMX8 microprocessor, does anybody know why could be failing?**

Comment: Reading e.g. [this manual page](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/libnetfilter-queue-doc/nfq_get_nfmark.3.en.html) say that the "[m]essage parsing functions" are deprecated. Maybe the functions you are using have been moved to another (linker) library to make the deprecation easier?

Comment: Could you show your code? Are you declaring the functions as C? From the error, I assume you are importing symbols as C++, so with C++ convention.

Comment: Cannot show the code, but it is a linking issue, I do not know which is the problem: annot open source file "libnfnetlink/libnfnetlink.h" (dependency of "libnetfilter_queue/libnetfilter_queue.h")C/C++(1696) It is not reading the library properly, perhaps I am not compiling in the correct way

Comment: Have you installed the development packages for the library?

Comment: Yep, all libnetfilter_queue package and libnetlink package.

Comment: And the `libnetfilter_queue-dev` (or similarly named) package? Though without it the compiler should have given you errors about missing header files before you come to the linking stage.

Comment: The following libraries have been installed: libnetfilter_queue_dev, libmnl-dev and libnfnetlink. The error stills remaining...